# Duality to find Maximum number of collinear points in given plane

Tags: algorithm

Given set of N points on a 2-D plane, find maximum number of collinear points from this set.
                                                                          Is there a O(n*2) solution for this using Duality algorithm ? Can someone explain if it is possible to use Duality here.

Comment: What kind of duality [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(optimization)) or [that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(projective_geometry))?

Comment: @arturgrzesiak: They're the same thing.

Comment: @tmyklebu did not know, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you need to use duality for this.  Map each pair of points to a line equation in some canonical form.  Find the line equation that shows up most often using an appropriate hash table.

(If you insist on using duality, note that three collinear points correspond to a point being hit by three lines in the dual to your point set.  This doesn't actually give you a speedup, though.)